# Ubuntu No Space Left issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I guess it's pretty common situation, but in my case, having Laravel 4.2 deployed on DigitalOcean VPS, i've got 3 times a problem with having no space left on server which is actually not true.

Previously i've just cleaned following folders and problem was solved:

- /tmp
- /var/log
- php artisan clear:cache

And the server was ready to go. But now, it does not helped at all.

Doing `df -i` gives me:

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      1310720 1310720     0  100% /
none             62724       2 62722    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             60010     402 59608    1% /dev
tmpfs            62724     317 62407    1% /run
none             62724       4 62720    1% /run/lock
none             62724       1 62723    1% /run/shm
none             62724       2 62722    1% /run/user
```

and `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G  8.2G   11G  45% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            235M  4.0K  235M   1% /dev
tmpfs            50M  348K   49M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            246M     0  246M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

What I should reffer to actually ? I've searched all over the web since this morning, found nothing. Any ideas ?

**==== UPDATED ====**

Having executed a following command `` I received an answer, here what I got as an output:

```
1 swapfile
      9 tmp
     11 root
    129 bin
    133 sbin
    292 boot
    934 etc
   9147 home
   9243 lib
  67598 usr
1122246 var
```

Answer (score 0):

You've run out of inodes on your filesystem.

Cleaning up useless inodes might be a hard work sometimes, but the following command might give you hints on which files are the ones which more inodes have and hopefully you can delete some of them (run it as `root`):

```
find / -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | less
```

This command will take some time to run, but it will return a list of files that most inode usage have.

**Note**: This command will return the inode usage for the *current* directory. Once it has returned the result, you can `cd` to the directory where you suspect you can do a better cleanup and run the command again with `find . ...` to see the next level until you find the culprit.

Comment: the problem I'm getting once I run your command, is: `sort: cannot create temporary file in '/tmp': No space left on device`. It's ridiculous, and how to avoid such issues ?

Comment: Try removing some temporary files in `/tmp` and run it again. It's hard to tell how to avoid it because that depends on the problem that you'll find out with the command above: maybe a file with too much hard links, too much files under a directory...

Comment: now it took a little more then 1 minute before the same message appeared : `sort: cannot create temporary file in '/tmp': No space left on device` ... any advice ? I can't remove any files from production server

Comment: after removing some files, i managed to get an answer from your command, and I put that output to my questions

Comment: I'd obviously start looking at the `/var` directory. Run the `find` command there (replacing `/` by `.`) and see what it says this time.

Comment: at first - any advice how to stop the OS to eat disk space each time I run an command or maybe it's automatically ?

Comment: Probably the command itself needs to create some temporary files and that's why it's complaining about space. Perhaps you can erase some temporary files or old logs inside `/var/log`?